# need help in solving segmentation fault in C

Tags: c

i am currently having issues with the segmentation fault. this is my project for school and i keep on getting the segmentation fault i dont know why. i was tasked to produce a program to read in the value from the txt file and display it in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    float training_input[90][8],training_output[90][1],testing_input[10][8],testing_output[10][1];
    int i;
    FILE *fpointer;
    fpointer= fopen("project.txt","r");
    for (i=0;i <=90; i++ )
    {
        fscanf(fpointer, "%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f",&training_input[i][0],&training_input[i][1],&training_input[i][2],&training_input[i][3],&training_input[i][4],&training_input[i][5],&training_input[i][6],&training_input[i][7],&training_input[i][8],&training_output[i][9]);
        printf("\n %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f ",training_input[i][0],training_input[i][1],training_input[i][2],training_input[i][3],training_input[i][4],training_input[i][5],training_input[i][6],training_input[i][7],training_input[i][8],training_output[i][9]);
    }
    for (i=91; 1<=101; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fpointer, "%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, ",&testing_input[i][0],&testing_input[i][1],&testing_input[i][2],&testing_input[i][3],&testing_input[i][4],&testing_input[i][5],&testing_input[i][6],&testing_input[i][7],&testing_input[i][8],&testing_output[i][9]);
        printf("\n %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f, %f, ",testing_input[i][0],testing_input[i][1],testing_input[i][2],testing_input[i][3],testing_input[i][4],testing_input[i][5],testing_input[i][6],testing_input[i][7],testing_input[i][8],testing_output[i][9]);
    }
    fclose (fpointer);
    return 0;
```

the segmentation fault always occur in the fscanf and printf.

Comment: `... ,&training_input[i][8],&training_output[i][9]);` is beyond the array bounds

Comment: `training_input[i][8]` is not possible because it's declared as `float training_input[90][8]`, therefore the max index is 7

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array defined with 90 elements in one dimension:

```
float training_input[90][8]
```

You cannot iterate on it like:

```
for (i=0;i <=90; i++ )
```

Because you will also try to access the index `90`, which is ouside the bounds of the array - the valid indices are from `0` to `89`. This is why you get a segmentation fault. The check in the loop must be `i < 90`.

Also, in the second loop, you are iterating up to `101`, while your array is defined as having 10 elements. This would be a second segmentation fault.

Comment: Furthermore, `training_output[i][9]` and `testing_output[i][9]` are also over reached.